# How to process a dataframe with multiple measuring time-columns and multiple measured variables, respectively

Tags: python, pandas

I am a novice to Python and I'm dealing with a problem of data-preprocessing for machine learning in pandas.
The data which I want to preprocess consist of n-measured variables, where each variable has its own "timestamps". Furthermore, the column-length of each measured variable differs (e.g. 50 measurements for variable a and 1000 measurements for variable b).
For machine learning, I need to interpolate the data. I want the timestamps of each measured variable to be the same. How do I effectively upsample and downsample such a dataframe?

First, I succesfully imported the data from the corresponding .dat file.

Then, I split the dataframe into a dataframe for each touple of time-point and measured value to remove all nan-Values.

Now, I got stuck how to upsample/ downsample these dataframes.
The time-vectors are always provided as the total process time in hh:mm:ss. Unfortunatly, it seems like, I can't use pandas resample-function here, as my time-points given in my data are not in the DateTime-format. Also, the process time itself will be of great interest for the machine-learning task. So I woudln't like to change the process-time to date-time.

Maybe you know a simple, effective method to handle my data?
For the machine learning tasks, some GBs of data are going to be processed, therefore an effectice method is of great interest for me.

```
'Import data'
 df = pd.read_csv('FILE', sep="\t",
                   names=['t_a','a','t_b','b','t_c','c', 
                          't_d','d','t_e','e','t_f','f',
                          't_g','g','t_h','h','t_i','i'],
                   parse_dates=['t_a','t_b','t_c',
                                't_d','t_e','t_f',
                                't_g','t_h','t_i'],
                   decimal = ',',
                   header=1)

"Split df into touple of respective measuring time-point and measured 
value"
"Then, Drop all nan-values"
dfs=np.split(df,[2],axis=1)
a=dfs[0]
a=a.dropna()

dfs=np.split(dfs[1],[2],axis=1)
b=dfs[0]
b=b.dropna()

dfs=np.split(dfs[1],[2],axis=1)
c=dfs[0]
c=c.dropna()

"And so on..."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I fixed the problem with parsing the process time as a Date-Time object as follows:

```
def parse_processtime(df, df_columns):
for col in df_columns:
    if df[col].dtype == object:
        df[col] = pd.to_timedelta(df[col], errors='ignore')

df = pd.read_csv('FILE', sep="\t",
                   names=['t_a','a','t_b','b','t_c','c', 
                          't_d','d','t_e','e','t_f','f',
                          't_g','g','t_h','h','t_i','i'],
                   parse_dates=['t_a','t_b','t_c',
                                't_d','t_e','t_f',
                                't_g','t_h','t_i'],
                   infer_datetime_format=True,
                   decimal = ',',
                   header=1)

## Parse process-time
parse_processtime(df, df.columns)
```